# Is the Planar Bubble created by a Planar Shepherd immobile for its duration or does it stay centered on its creator?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, class-feature, planes

The Planar Shepherd prestige class offers an ability at 5th level to temporarily apply the traits of a specific plane (chosen when you first take levels in the class) to the area around you.

Given the ability says the area is created "around yourself" and has a concentration-based duration measured in hours, I would assume the bubble moves with you, but is there anything that definitively states one way or another?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Up to the DM

As so many things in D&D, the phrasing is vague enough that DM adjudication is necessary.

> **Planar Bubble (Su)**: Beginning at 5th level, once per day you can create
> an area around yourself that emulates the environment of your chosen
> plane. This area mimics all traits of your chosen plane, including
> physical traits, elemental and energy traits, alignment traits, and
> magic traits. This area has a 20-foot radius and lasts as long as you
> concentrate (up to a maximum of 1 hour per level) plus 1d10 rounds.

The key descriptor here is, "you can create an area around yourself", which does *not* specify which of the two valid interpretations you propose is the definite one.

- The area is created **around yourself**, as in your **then-current position**, and remains there if you move away from it.
- The area is created **around yourself**, as in **around whatever position you are in for the duration of the effect**.

I would judge it to be the latter, because we are dealing with a Supernatural ability I read functioning as basically **your close association with another plane** warping space around you, seeing as how there's no range mentioned. But **your DM** is the arbiter in your game, not me.